# Adding interaction term with multiple variables in gamm4?

Tags: interaction, error-message, gamm4

I am using `gamm4` model from R package `gamm4` (random slope=age_m, random intercept=FLEHS_ID and groupdescription):

**m1 I only look at the interaction between pfoa_ter (categorical) and age_m (continuous):**

```
m1 <- gamm4::gamm4(BMIzscore ~ + s(age_m, by=pfoa_ter, m=1) + 
                   pfoa_ter +s(age_m),
                   random = ~ (1 + age_m|FLEHS_ID) +  
                   (1 + age_m|groupdescription),
                           data=Flehs1s_2, REML=FALSE)
```

**m2 I would like to look at interaction between `pfoa_ter` (categorical) and `age_m` (continuous) and sex (categorical), so I ran the model as below but it does not work:**

```
m2 <- gamm4::gamm4(BMIzscore ~ + te(age_m, by=pfoa_ter, by=sex, 
                   m=1) + pfoa_ter +s(age_m),
                   random = ~ (1+age_m|FLEHS_ID) +  
                   (1 + age_m|groupdescription),
                   data=Flehs1s_2, REML=FALSE)

Error in s(age_m, by = sex, by = pfoa_ter, m = 1) : 
  formal argument "by" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

Anyone can help with adding an interaction term with multiple variables (one continuous + two categorical) in `gamm4` with `s()` or `te()`? or any other solution?